# How to obtain URL that Flash movie is embedded on?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, url, loaderinfo

today I'm trying to get the URL where my Flash movie is sitting on.

I found [**a similar question here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396412/how-can-my-flash-app-determine-its-own-url), which was answered with a [link to Flash's LoaderInfo](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#includeExamplesSummary) method, but I'm not sure I'm using it correctly as the textField in my test movie here: http://leongaban.com/stackoverflow/getUrl/ does not display the URL

### Updated! WORKING CODE

All I needed was this: `stage.loaderInfo.url` :)

```
package {

import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import FontsTest;

public class LoaderInfoExample extends Sprite 
{
    private var myTextField :TextField = new TextField();
    private var urlIs:String = "";

    public function LoaderInfoExample() {

        urlIs = stage.loaderInfo.url;
        trace(stage.loaderInfo.url);
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initHandler);
    }

    private function initHandler(event:Event):void {

        myTextField.defaultTextFormat = FontsTest.Arial14Bold;
        myTextField.border = true;
        myTextField.antiAliasType = flash.text.AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        myTextField.selectable = true;
        myTextField.mouseEnabled = true;
        myTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        myTextField.text = "Url is = "+urlIs;

        addChild(myTextField);
    }
}
}
```

http://leongaban.com/stackoverflow/getUrl/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you're doing it just a little bit wrong. You don't need to create a new loader - the .swf holds a reference to its own loaderInfo object on stage.

So if you want to trace out the current location of your .swf file, do something like this:

```
trace(stage.loaderInfo.url);
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

If its your own URL you're after, the DisplayObject class has a loaderInfo property you can use. Try this:

```
myLoader = this.root.loaderInfo;
urlIs = myLoader.loaderURL;
```

I'm relatively sure that loader object you're creating isn't going to have a loaderURL (or do anything else) until you tell it to load a request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an `onAddedToStage` instead of the `Event.INIT`

```
public function LoaderInfoExample() {
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initHandler);
}
```

and then use `root.loaderInfo`

Comment: what import is needed so I can use the root keyword? And thanks for the tip!

Comment: root is part of the DisplayObject so extending Sprite should be enough.